# Google Cloud Go Handler without Router Gorilla Mux?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, router

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/users/

I see here that they do not specify to use any router...: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig

In Google Cloud when used with Golang, it says to specify every handler in `app.yaml`. Does this mean we are not supposed to use 3rd party router for better performance? I would like to Gorilla `Mux` for router... How would it work if I use other routers for Google App Engine Golang App?

Please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use Gorilla Mux with App Engine. Here's how:

At the end of the handlers section of [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig), add a script handler that routes all paths to the Go application:

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:

- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg)$

- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

The `_go_app` script is the Go program compiled by App Engine. The pattern `/.*` matches all paths.

The main function generated by App Engine dispatches all requests to the [DefaultServeMux](http://godoc.org/net/http#DefaultServeMux).

In an init() function, create and configure a Gorilla [Router](http://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Router). Register the Gorilla router with the DefaultServeMux to handle all paths:

```
func init() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", homeHandler)

    // The path "/" matches everything not matched by some other path.
    http.Handle("/", r)
}
```